# Tomcat/websocket responding with error 404

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have developed a web site locally on my mac using tomcat 8.0.027 and java jdk 7. The site relies on websockets and all works well locally. When I deploy the site to a virtual private java server I get an error 404. The url for the websocket is ws://www.modelstudio3d.com/handler, my site is www.modelstudio3d.com. I've tried appending :8080 to the host name, that changes the error to connection refused. Changing the url to ../handlerx also generates a connection refused. I've checked that I'm not packaging additional websocket jars in my war file (I'm not as far as I can tell). My server is running tomcat 8.0.22 and JDK 7. My ISP is unable to provide any guidance.

My client code is

```
this.getWebSocketURI = function () {
    var loc = window.location, wsUri;
    if (loc.protocol === "https:") {
        wsUri = "wss:";
    } else {
        wsUri = "ws:";
        console.log("Websocket is not secure.");
    }
    wsUri += "//" + loc.host;
    wsUri += loc.pathname + "handler";
    console.log("wsUri" + wsUri);
    return wsUri;
};

this.init = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.websocket = new WebSocket(self.getWebSocketURI());
...
```

The interesting part of the server code is

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/handler", 
            configurator = GetHttpSessionConfigurator.class)
public class WebSocket {
```

I've read something here about an Apache location filter that might be interfering by redirecting ws: to http: but have no idea where that resides or how to change it.

Comment: I've not identified your problem, but I do know the implementation of WebSocket has changed significantly since your early version of Tomcat. I suggest switching to the latest version, especially 8.5.x.

Comment: That's going to be tricky. I've worked with this hosting service before and you only get to pick from their menu of versions.

Comment: I've also tried removing the configurator, that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

My hosting service finally agreed to investigate the problem. They say mod_proxy_wstunnel is not enabled and cannot be enabled. Don't use Mocha Host if you need to use websockets.